# React Router - ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm a beginner to React and I'm having issues which I have no idea how they even arose on a React project I've been playing with.

Obviously I'm assuming the error is to do with the React Router package but I've no idea how its come about and how I can fix it so any help would be great. Here's the full error message:

```
Compiled with warnings.

Failed to parse source map from '/Users/X/crm/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/X/crm/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx'

Failed to parse source map from '/Users/X/crm/packages/react-router/index.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/X/crm/packages/react-router/index.tsx'

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-router-dom/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/X/crm/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/X/crm/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx'

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-router/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/X/crm/packages/react-router/index.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/X/crm/packages/react-router/index.tsx'

webpack compiled with 2 warnings
```

Thank you very much!

I've tried to run the app, expected it to run and the error message has arose.

Comment: Make sure you've actually saved any project files of yours and try again. These source map paths look odd, like you tried recreating `react-router` and `react-router-dom` index files yourself. Maybe delete the node_modules directory and re-run `npm install` to reinstall all the project's dependencies. Outside of this I think you'll need to [edit] your post to include a [mcve] of the code you are using and the code the error refers to and the exact reproduction steps you are doing to reproduce the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete  `node modules`  and `package-lock.json` files.
2. `npm install`
3. `run npm start`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Did you mean `npm run start`?

Answer (score 0):

You might have change the version of React-Router-Dom more than once. It basically happened when you change any version or react-router-dom or React-router. The file path get mismatch and saved with the index.js.

You can once check you path files for eg: *your_path_file*\packages\react-router\index.tsx' it will be replaced.
Also you get a warning in your node_modules that your file is missing as node module already have added that file for you and the name got change once you have change the React-Router-Dom vesrsions.

[image]